# XML Comments for Abstract methods in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, documentation, intellisense

Say you have an Abstract Class with Abstract methods, and you place XML Documentation Tags on those methods.

When you inherit from that class, and implement those methods, intellisense does not "inherit" the XML Documentation...?

**Does anyone know if its possible to make the IDE inherit the documentation?**

if not, don't you think this is kind of strange behavior?

I think its quite acceptable that I might want generic comments to bubble up through implementations of a Class...and of course, if I comment an implementation, then that should appear instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) will automatically inherit the documentation.  It's my #2 favorite plug-in next to ReSharper.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> ... documented!

Comment: cool, thanks womp, I'll check it out. Shame VS can't do it natively.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the documentation inherited - you have to document each code element explicitly.

Try [AtomineerUtils](http://atomineer.com/AtomineerUtils.html) - it's a free alternative to GhostDoc which is much more powerful and configurable. It'll gather as much information as possible from any existing documentation (both for overridden base-class methods/properties and overloaded methods), in addition to auto-generation of documentation from element naming, to minimise the amount of manual labour involved in documentation of code elements.